# Is it possible to adapt and existing NLP tool in english to Swedish? and what´s the best approach?

Tags: artificial-intelligence, nlp

Whats the best approach of using existing NLP tools in english with another language ex.spanish ?

Answer (score 0):

That's an awfully broad question, and you'd need to provide some more pointers. However, if you're interested in general research on the topic, you can try Hana, Feldman, Brew (2004) "Tagging Russian using Czech morphology" and Resnik's 2004 "Using bilingual text for monolingual annotation" and start from there.

In general, you'd want to have a bicorpus (say, English/Swedish). Then establish mappings using alignment (that's a common topic in machine translation with many established results.)

You can then tag the English side, and use the mapping to "translate" these mappings into the Swedish side. Then you can train the same tool that created the mappings on the English side using the newly annotated Swedish corpus.

It goes without saying that you'll lose quite a bit of quality and that this technique only works for supervised methods. You should probably try to find properly annotated Swedish corpora and tools. There are a few out there.

Comment: Here's an anecdote about "zero-shot" language supprt (in a longer podcast marnly about other topics) where a big model which was trained for English would incidentally work for some other languages too, presumably because it simply happened to receive enough ("noisy") training data in some other languages too. https://changelog.com/practicalai/32